# Multiple line cells from csv to R transaction matrix

Tags: r, csv, apriori, arules

I've got the following problem (which is actually two problems): I have a csv-file with transactions. But all the items bought with a transactionID are stored in multiple lines of a single cell.

It looks like this

```
TransactionID    Items

1234             Milk
                 Butter
                 Bread

2345             Milk
                 Bread

3456             Beer
                 Milk

4567             Beer
                 Butter
```

As you can see not all items are used in each transaction.

How can I import my data in R as a transaction matrix that looks like this

```
TransactionID    Milk    Butter    Bread    Beer
1234             1       1         1        0
2345             1       0         1        0
3456             1       0         0        1
4567             0       1         0        1
```

Can it be done in a single, elegant step?
After the import I want to analyze my data using the arules package.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Including pictures of data is not very helpful. See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to include all the necessary information in the question itself.

Comment: Tried to fix readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not single line and assumes that words are split by blank space. I find the unique words first then do a double loop.

```
u <- unique(do.call('c', strsplit(df$items, ' ')))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in u) {
    df[i, j] <- 1 * (j %in% strsplit(df$items[i], ' ')[[1]])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DirkNachbar! Your approach worked and definetely pushed me in the right direction. Just some small adjustment was necessary: The words were split by a linebreak.

Afterwards I added the matrix to a file and re-impoted it for arules.

```
write(mat, file = "TransactionMatrix", sep = "\n")
trans = read.transactions("TransactionMatrix", format = "basket", sep = "\n")
```

The Problem about this approach is the runtime. With several ten thousand transactions and a few thousand items it takes ages to compute the matrix.

Since my final goal was importing into arules´ transaction matrix format I eventually used another approach and concatenated all items to one large list.

```
df <- read.csv("Transactions.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")

MaxTransactions <- 0
for (i in 1:length(df$items)) {

    add <- length(strsplit(as.character(df$items[i]),'\n')[[1]])
    MaxTransactions <- MaxTransactions + add
    }

IDs <- rep(NA, MaxTransactions)
ITEMs <- rep(NA, MaxTransactions)

Position <- 0

for (i in 1:length(df$items)) {

    tempITEM <- c(strsplit(as.character(df$items[i]),'\n')[[1]])
    tempID <- rep(as.character(df$TransID[i]),length(tempITEM))

    for (j in 1:length(tempITEM)) {
        IDs[Position+j] <- tempID[j]
        ITEMs[Position+j] <- tempITEM[j]
        }
    Position <- Position + length(tempITEM)
    }
```

That allowed me to coerce to a arules´ transaction matrix from a "transaction" format instead of "basket" format.

```
a_df <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(IDs),ITEM = as.factor(ITEMs))

TransList <- split(a_df[,"ITEM"],a_df[,"ID"]) 
TransMat <- as(TransList, "transactions")
```

This worked well for me.